# Как удалить ошибку «TypeError: squareGen is not a function»?

Tags: javascript

Выполняю простое решение задач, но попался на распространненую ошибку и не могу понять почему так. Прошу объяснить. Код длинный состоящий из 4-х частей.

Ошибка возникает в четвёртой части (`task-4`). При проверке через `typeof`, `squareGen === 'number'`. Почему `'number'`?

```js
// task-1
function sequence(start, step) {
  step = step || 1;
  start = start || 0;
  let flag = false,
    firstStep = 0;
  return function() {
    if (flag) {
      return start += step;
    } else {
      flag = true;
      return start += firstStep;
    }

  }
}
var generator = sequence(10, 3);
var generator2 = sequence(7, 1);
var generator3 = sequence(0, 2);

// task-2

function take(fn, steps) {
  let array = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
    array.push(fn());
  }
  return array;
}

// task-3

function square(x) {
  return x * x;
}
console.log(map(square, [1, 2, 3, 4])); // [1, 4, 9, 16]
console.log(map(square, [])); // []
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(map(square, arr)); // [1, 4, 9]
console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3]

function map(fn, array) {
  let mas = array,
    newArray = [];
  mas.forEach(function(el) {
    newArray.push(fn(el));
  });
  return newArray;
}

// task-4

function fmap(a, gen) {
  let resultOfGen = gen();
  return a(resultOfGen);
}

var gen = sequence(1, 1);
var squareGen = fmap(square, gen);
squareGen();
console.log(typeof squareGen);
console.log(squareGen()); // 1
console.log(squareGen()); // 4
console.log(squareGen()); // 9
console.log(squareGen()); // 16
```

Comment: `fmap` возвращает результат вызова функции `a`, которая в данном случае - `square`. Результат этой функции - число, и при попытке вызвать его как функцию ты получаешь логичное сообщение

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался)